# Combobox selection change in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Combobox` and two buttons in my `UserControl`. Is it possible to set those button to change the selected index of the `Combobox` directly in XAML?

I have done this by two approaches:

Code-behind

```
 private void nextBut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            combo.SelectedIndex++;
        }

        private void prevBut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            combo.SelectedIndex--;
        }
```

Or by binding commands to those buttons and define that command in my `ModelView`.

I have another question about XAML and I really don't know if ask a different question or use this opportunity that you are already reading me! I'm sure it has to be straightforward (at least for WPF gurus around here):

I have a `ItemsControl` that holds that `UserControl`, but there may be several or none (because you can create more, or delete). I want a `Checkbox` outside that is enabled or not depending if there are or not elements in my `ItemsContol` (disable if there is nothing). I think this can be done with Command Validation but looks difficult to me as I'm new in this world. This also could be done with codebehind but I would like to avoid it. (Like defining a bool property bound to that `Checkbox`, as write something like `if(myItems.Count==0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather bind the `SelectedItem` property to some property in the ViewModel, and bind  these buttons to some Commands in  the  ViewModel. This way keep the state data (selectedItem) in the ViewModel, and can use that to perform any additional logic required, removing the need for code behind.

For the CheckBox, I'd rather put a bool property in the ViewModel,  and notify that whenever you add/remove items.

```
public bool HasItems {get {return Items.Any(); } }

public void AddItem()
{
    //...Add Items
    NotifyPropertyChanged("HasItems");
}

public void RemoveItem()
{
    //...Remove Item
    NotifyPropertyChanged("HasItems");
}
```

This removes the need for an additional converter.

Comment: Elegant. Clever.  Nicely conceived!

Answer (score 2):

For the checkbox issue, it comes under the generic issue of converting a quantity into a bool.  A canonical WPF answer would be bind the checkbox IsChecked property to the collection and route it through an IValueConverter.  Here is a converter to do just that...

```
public class QuantityToBoolConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable items = value as IEnumerable;
            if (items != null)
            {
                return items.OfType<object>().Any();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

To deploy it, you would need to declare it in your Xaml as a resource...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:QuantityToBoolConverter x:Key="QuantityToBoolConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then bind the IsChecked property to your items and declare the converter...

```
<ListBox Name="mylb">
</ListBox>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=mylb, Path=ItemsSource, Converter={StaticResource 
                  QuantityToBoolConverter}}"></CheckBox>
```

For the combobox SelectedIndex issue, you can check out the CollectionViewSource docs. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)  You can manipulate this in your ViewModel to move the current selection.  And there's tons of sample code to examine.  Knowing the ICollectionView will serve you well as a WPF developer.

Comment: +1. Though I prefer to keep things simple. Additionaly, I'd rather inherit all  my converters from `MarkupExtension`, thus removing the need to instantiate them as resources.

Comment: Massively valuable tip on inheriting from MarkupExtension.  Whoooosh!  That's the sound of me off to change my converter library!